# Substitutions in a string between a start regex and an end regex

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to do multiple substitutions within a string but only when between a start regex and an end regex. For example:

```
$start = qr/a.*?b/;
$end = qr/c.*?d/;
$string = 'a1b x c2d x a345b qqxxxc678d xx abxcd';
```

The perl code will do a restricted `s/x/y/g`. It will change all `x`s that occur between `a.*?b` & `c.*?d` to `y` so that afterwards:

```
$string = 'a1b y c2d x a345b qqyyyc678d xx abycd'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complication that you need global replacement but only within marker patterns can be handled by capturing that substring and running a regex on it in the replacement part

```
my $s = q(a1b x and x c2d x more x  a22b x again x c33d x and x); 

$s =~ s/a.*?b\K(.*?)(?=c.*?d)/ $1 =~ s{x}{y}gr /eg;

say $s;
```

With `/e` modifier the replacement part is evaluated as code, so we can run any valid Perl there and its return is used as the replacement string.

I use `\K` after the left-marker pattern (`a.*?b`) to drop previous matches and a lookahead for the right-marker pattern (`c.*?d`), so to not have those copied  around, but for simplicity you can capture them instead and use the number variables (`$N`) for them in replacement.

Consider capturing the right marker (instead of a lookahead) if the pattern repeats; then for an extra data copy the subpattern isn't scanned repeatedly and the overall regex is cleaner, and in principle safer (can the right marker possibly contain the left marker?). This does complicate the replacement part, where `$2` need be saved away before the new regex since it gets reset in it.

Note the `/r` modifier in the replacement part's regex: other than being very convenient it also allows us to use `s///` on the `$1` variable, what otherwise we couldn't do since it's read only.

If this is a part of more complex regex processing then note that a lookahead is a zero-width *assertion* so the engine doesn't consume that pattern and doesn't pass it. This matters if the whole pattern repeats: If it is possible that the right marker contains the left marker then you must capture it so that the engine moves past it for the next match, so that the left marker comes first for it.

---

This works with variables for marker patterns, which you nicely use

```
my $start = qr/a.*?b/;
my $end   = qr/c.*?d/;

my $s = q(a1b x and x c2d x more x  a22b x again x c33d x and x); 

$s =~ s/$start\K (.*?) (?=$end)/ $1 =~ s{x}{y}gr /egx;

say $s;
```

where I've spaced patterns around for readability, by courtesy of `/x`.   It prints

```
a1b y and y c2d x more x  a22b y again y c33d x and x
```

Comment: I'm slowly understanding the use of \K, btw.. I changed to ````(?=a.*?b)```` and got same results.. so how can I differentiate when to replace \K with positive lookahead?

Comment: @stack0114106 Heh, interesting ... didn't think of that :)  I suppose it comes up to that string and asserts it's there, without consuming it -- but then it also matches (and consumes) what's after it? Not sure how that works and whether it works in all cases. A "normal" thing to do would be a lookbehind, but those can't be of "variable length" so that's out (because of `.*` part which may be a character or five -- variable in length). However, `\K` is there and handy. Note that it, too, comes with subtleties.

Comment: @stack0114106 Here are some thoughts on using one or the other. If there's a reason to (match but) not consume, that's a lookaround. When I just want to drop matches so not to have to capture and "replace" (put them back!) then that's `\K`.  The lookahead is to assert a pattern after what I need; the `\K` forgets what came before what I need. In other words, if there's stuff of interest after a pattern I wouldn't use lookahead for it, but a normal match (and then drop it with `\K` if I don't want it captured)

Comment: @stack0114106 Example. (1) Remove everything after (the last) `$p` pattern: `s/.*$p\K.*//`  (2) Remove a word before `$p` pattern: `s/(\w+)(?=$p)//`.  In both cases we can of course capture and put back what needs to stay, instead.  I'd say that lookarounds have far more substantial uses though -- they may nicely solve a problem which would be a nightmare otherwise. The `\K` ... not so much perhaps; more of a convenience.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `/e` modified to execute code (for each match separately) to generate the replacement string:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $start_regex  = qr/a.*?b/;
my $end_regex    = qr/c.*?d/;
my $string = 'a1b x c2d x a345b qqxxxc678d xx abxcd';

$string =~ s/($start_regex)(.*?)($end_regex)/ my ($start_match, $middle_match, $end_match) = ($1, $2, $3); $middle_match =~ s!x!y!g; $start_match . $middle_match . $end_match /eg;

print $string, "\n";
```

Will print out

```
a1b y c2d x a345b qqyyyc678d xx abycd
```

Note the alternate regex delimiter `s!!!` in the inner regex.

It's important to store the `$1`, `$2` and `$3` of the outer regex match in temporary variables, since they'll be lost when you do another regex in the replacement code.